# What's the cardinality of $\{ (i,j,k) : i+j+k=10, i,j,k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ ? General case.

Tags: combinatorics

How many triples of natural numbers are there of sum equal to 10? What about the cardinality of

$$\{ (n_1,...,n_K) : \ n_i \in \mathbb{N} \ \wedge \sum_{i=1}^{K} n_i=N \ \} \ ?$$

Is there an intuitive way of thinking about this? I'm looking for a simple argument how to count this.

Comment: Yeah, I'll delete this. Nvm, can't since there's an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard [stars-and-bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) problem; the linked article gives both a formula and a pretty decent explanation of the reasoning underlying it. Assuming that your $\Bbb N$ includes $0$, the answer to the specific problem is

$$\binom{10+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{12}2\;;$$

if your $\Bbb N$ does not include $0$, it’s

$$\binom{10-1}{3-1}=\binom92\;.$$